# Predicate Logic and Laws of Form

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In Spencer Browns Laws of Form he mentions in Appendix 2, that LoF is powerful enough to express First Order Logic but in "Kalkül der Form" by Dieter Baecker is written, that LoF is not 'powerful' enough to express quantifiers. So are there some good resourcces for explaining why it is possible or why not? At least I did only find this one explicit mentioning in "Kalkül der Form" but not really a mathematical explanation, why it is not possible.

Comment: In Laws of Form, all example with predicate logic are restricted to syllogisms that in modern form are [Monadic Predicate Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_predicate_calculus): a subsystem of FOL.

Comment: So it is for example not possible to express formulas like: $ \forall x \exists y : x + y = y + x $ I don't mean provable just the expression of this formula?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not an expert of LoF's system (that is quite convoluted) and it seems that (in contrast with the propositional part) there are no easily accessible documentation regarding the predicate part. Thus, we have only "second-hand" statements contrasting Spencer-Brown's bold assertion regarding "the solution of **all** problems"... :-(

Comment: *Lof* is the logical monism view compared to popular logical pluralism view when one learned there're so many different logics with different inference rules applicable to different use cases. If you believe in logical monism, Lof is one viable candidate though its power is not in quantification, but in treating self-reference in a non-othordoxical unique way...

Answer (score 2):

Laws of form is essentially an extended Boolean algebra, there's variant called [complete Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean-valued_model) being able to express quantifiers. Also another variant called [cylindric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindric_algebra) functions similarly which you may take a look.